# sql count function join

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT c.cname, COUNT(e.ccode) 
FROM class c
INNER JOIN enrolled e ON e.ccode = c.ccode
WHERE room = 'MB100'
AND e.ccode = < 10;
```

I'm trying to find the names of courses that are in room MB100 that have less than 10 students, where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `group by c.cname`, Try this:

```
SELECT c.cname, COUNT(e.ccode) 
FROM class c
INNER JOIN enrolled e ON e.ccode = c.ccode
WHERE room = 'MB100'
Group by c.cname
Having e.ccode =< 10;
```

Comment: +1 Didn't spot that was missing too. But you need to use `HAVING COUNT(e.ccode) < 10;  `

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, Actually once I saw your answer I deleted mine, the +77k repatution makes me doubt in my answer :)